# App crashes when presenting a view (popover) for a second time

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I've just stumbled across this issue and was wondering if anyone could help explain the problem.

When in use on an iPad, my view has a nested `UINavigationController` that is displayed within a popover. I've been converting this code to Swift recently and attempted to use lazy initialisation as follows:

```
lazy var secondaryNavigationController: UINavigationController = {
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: menuView)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    navController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = menuButton
    return navController
}()
```

*Note that menuView and menuButton are also lazily initialised*

I then tried to present the view as follows:

```
@objc private func openMenu() {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        present(secondaryNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(menuView, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The first time I open the menu everything works okay, the menu displays as expected. However if I dismiss the menu by tapping another area of the screen and then try to reopen it for a second time, I get the following crash:

> UIPopoverPresentationController () should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set
>   before the presentation occurs.

This crash goes away if I make the following change to the `openMenu()` function:

```
@objc private func openMenu() {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        secondaryNavigationController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = menuButton // hurrah!
        present(secondaryNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(menuView, animated: true)
    }
}
```

So is the fix above necessary? Am I missing anything obvious that would allow it to be set within the lazy initialisation block?

---

**(Crash Log from example project)**

> 2018-06-29 21:13:09.836061+0100 PopoverBugExample[90568:1465443] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController
>   () should have a
>   non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation
>   occurs.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110c4b7f6 **exceptionPreprocess + 294  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010f2a3035 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   UIKitCore
>
>   0x0000000113323a0e -[UIPopoverPresentationController
>   presentationTransitionWillBegin] + 3168   3   UIKitCore
>
>   0x000000011332d568 __71-[UIPresentationController
>   _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke + 2495  4   UIKitCore                           0x000000011332ab5c
>   __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 468   5   UIKitCore
>
>   0x0000000112fd8965 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 318  6
>
>   UIKitCore                           0x0000000112fc77d3
>   _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 397    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000112ff7131 _afterCACommitHandler + 141  8   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000110baee97
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ba92ce
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430  10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ba9971 __CFRunLoopRun + 1553    11  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000110ba9021 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625     12  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000011825c16e GSEventRunModal + 62   13  UIKitCore
>   0x0000000112fcd3ff UIApplicationMain + 140    14  PopoverBugExample
>   0x000000010e97c857 main + 71  15  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00000001120dce61 start + 1  16  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: I suspect that the issue is that `menuButton` isn't owned by `secondaryNavigationController`, and when the popup is dismissed it is deallocated. What happens if you don't make `menuButton` `lazy`?

Comment: Please share your crash logs here

Comment: @Anita see edit for crash logs :)

Comment: @Grimxn - What alternative to lazy init did you have in mind? I gave it a try by just declaring it as a standard var and initialising in viewDidLoad, but unfortunately the behaviour was the same (crash on the second attempt to load).

Had a quick read of the docs and I'm starting to suspect that the popoverPresentationController instance is the issue. I think a new instance is created each time, but with the lazy init approach the barbutton is only set for the first instance.

The `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` could be worth a try.

Comment: I think you've sussed it out when you say "a new instance is created each time, but with the lazy init approach the barbutton is only set for the first instance" - but you've also fixed it! My comment was a guess (hence not an answer), so I suggest you answer your own question...